# How to print collection of ID cards in one print like Microsoft Office Publisher?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, report, printdocument

In my application I have a form which is used to create a staff id card. All is good but I am facing a problem on printing it by adding all selected id cards to a page(s). Like it is very easy to print approximately 4 landscape cards in 1 page, which can be done using both print document method as well as rdlc report. Where I used printdocument's PrintPage event to do the job and rdlc report's parameter. But both are limited to 4 cards per print. But what I want is lets say there are twenty new employees/ staffs whose ID cards are required and I want to print them all at once.

### What I tried?

**PrintDocument Method**

Add all the ID cards to a DataGridView and then use this code on the PrintPage Event of the PrintDocument

```
Dim i as integer = 25
For j as Integer = 0 To dgv.rowcount - 1
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(dgv.rows(j).Cells(0).Value, 25, i, 375, 236)
   i += 241
Next
i = 25
```

> But this can only print up to 4 cards per print. I tried to use `e.HasMorePages = True` but couldn't make it work to get what I want.

**RDLC Report Mothod**

Creating a DataSet, DS1, and adding a tables with same column name as my datagridview column name and then create a rdlc report with DataSet, DS1, and adding a table in it with only the image column to be visible.

> But unfortunately this was the biggest fail in this case as it cannot even show a single picture. So I had an option to create pictures on the report and use the Parameter method to get the values from the form which again restricts me from printing more than 4 cards per print.

Comment: The point of the `PrintPage` event handler is to print a page.  If you can only fit four cards on a page then you need to only draw four cards in the event handler. You need to keep track of how many cards you've already drawn and start at the next one each time. `HasMorePages` is set to `True` if an only if there is more to print.

Comment: Yeah mate you are right! That’s what I am trying to do but not being able to do it. A little coding suggestion migh be a great help... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of printing a list of items over multiple pages.  In this case, it's done four to a page.

```
Const ITEMS_PER_PAGE As Integer = 4

Private items As List(Of Object)
Private itemIndex As Integer

Private Sub PrintDocument1_BeginPrint(sender As Object, e As PrintEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.BeginPrint
    'Start from the beginning of the list.
    itemIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    For i = 1 To ITEMS_PER_PAGE
        If itemIndex = items.Count Then
            'We're done.
            Exit For
        End If

        Dim item = items(itemIndex)

        'Print item here.

        itemIndex += 1
    Next

    'Print another page if and only if we are not at the end of the list.
    e.HasMorePages = itemIndex < items.Count
End Sub
```

Note that `itemIndex` maintains its value between invocations of the `PrintPage` event handler.

Comment: Hey @jmcilhinney sorry for late :(

I am having difficulty on understanding the list(of object)

how can I use it to print array or dgv rows?

Comment: +1 Wow I am getting some parts... hope I figure it out thanks dude... :) please wish me a luck... I replaced list(of object) with string and used it as array...

Comment: As I said, this is just an example of printing a list.  You can replace that `List(Of Object)` with any list at all, e.g. `String` array, `Rows` collection of a `DataGridView` or whatever. It's simply exemplifying the fact that you can access the items in a list in pages in order to print one page at a time. What the list is, what the items in that list are and how you actually draw those items will differ for each specific case but the pattern of the code will remain the same regardless.

Comment: Hey!! I did it :) thanks a lot dude!!! Do you know if we can export printdocument pages into pictures or pdfs? which is easier with clear printable quality.

Comment: A `PrintDocument` doesn't have pages. It manages the printing, including sending what needs to be printed to the printer (at a high level at least) but it doesn't actually contain the printed pages in any sense.

Comment: Notice that the `PrintPage` event handler uses a `Graphics` object to do the drawing. It gets that object from the `e.Graphics` property. What you can do is move the drawing code into a method that takes a `Graphics` object as an argument and then call it from multiple places with different objects, e.g. from the `PrintPage` event handler and elsewhere with the result of calling `Graphics.FromImage`. You can then print with one call and draw on a `Bitmap` with another.

Comment: See [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?426684-Very-Simple-Drawing-Program) for an example of what I'm talking about. It uses a `Paint` event rather than a `PrintPage` event but it does as I said above and moves the drawing code to its own method and then calls it from two different places with two different `Graphics` objects with one of the being from an `Image`.

Comment: You might also consider that you could just draw on a `Bitmap` to begin with, then call `DrawImage` to print it. That way, creating an `Image` of what's being printed is part of the printing process itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful suggestions... After reading all your comments I think I should try to create a array of bitmap where each new bitmap when new page is called and then save them. Do you think it is a good idea? :D

Comment: Sounds reasonable, although a `List(Of Bitmap)` is probably the better choice.. You could actually create all the `Bitmaps` first and then that would be the list that you use for `items`, with the item printing code being a single call to `DrawImage`.

Comment: Yeah that would be nice but won't that result in saving image file for each card rather than 4 cards in 1 image? Like for four cards images saved will be 4 and print page will be 1. Am I wrong?

Comment: It depends on how you implement it. If you have the four-iteration loop in the part where you create the `Images` then you can draw four cards to each. You would then just draw one `Image` per `PrintPage` event.